# How can i get my application shortcut to show up in the device?

Tags: android, shortcut

I am using Activity-alias in AndroidManifest.xml to specify another entry point to my application using shortcut. I am seeing the shortcut in the shortcut list. How can I get my 2nd icon (shortcut) to show in the Home?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not seeing your launcher icon at all, see the third activity in this [ApplicationManifest.xml](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Photostream/AndroidManifest.xml) for an example of an  declaration.

If by "shortcut list" you mean the app menu, then you can just hold and drag the icon with your finger and it will allow you to drop it on your Home screen.